# Too much spacing

Tags: php, css

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00YP7.jpg)

> I need the item name and price to be underneath the 'burger' and not
>   some down below. I dont know if its relevant but the menu is read fro
>   a database.code i used to do this is below":

```
.burgers{
  display: inline-block;
 float:right;
  margin-top:1400px;
  margin-right:100px; 
}
#image3 {
    background-image: url(burgers.jpg);

    background-position: 0% 1575px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-size: 750px 460px;
    padding: 0px;


}
.font{
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size:22px;
      display: inline-block;  
}
<br><br><div2 class="burgers"><h2>Burgers</h2><br>  
<div2b class=font>
    <?php
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++) {
    if($array[$i]["Food_Category"]=="burgers"){
            echo   str_repeat('&nbsp;', 4).$array[$i]["Food_Name"]. "   " .str_repeat('.&nbsp;', 25). "€".$array[$i]["Food_Price"]."<br>";
    }
    ?>
    </div2b>
    </div2>
```

Comment: What on earth are `<div2b>` and `<div2>` ? shouldn't they be open and closed `<div>` ? start fixing those first.

Comment: I don't see any style tags, I guess you didn't post the full code? Your are missing a } to end the for-loop. Please post the entire code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `img` tag in the HTML

Comment: You right, but I thought  there no full code given for us.